# I have two lists of strings in kotlin, how to concatenate each element of the first list with elements of the second one respective to the positions?

Tags: kotlin

I have two lists:

```
val a = listOf("a", "b", "c")
val b = listOf("1", "2", "3")
```

I want to get a list that looks like this: `["a1", "b2", "c3"]`.
How to do this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would look like this:

```
val c = a.zip(b).map {it.first + it.second }
```

Comment: You can also use a `transform` function with zip in order to remove `map` like so: `a.zip(b){a, b -> a+b }`